# How do I host an internal rubygem source?

Tags: rubygems

We'd like to host a rubygems source internally on our own network, because while we do want to use gems as a distribution mechanism, we don't want to publish our gems externally to the company, since the scripts are perforce very specific to our environment (Windows).

Where can I find instructions on how to do such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found via http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/18.

`gem server`

at a command line starts up a local gem server on port 8808.

Comment: you can create a directory (say gemsource) under a web server's tree, create a subdirectory called "gems", put your gems there and then run "gem generate_index ." in gemsource.